# How to dynamically add nested elements to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

There its a `dict t = {}` 
when

```
count = 1 
t = {'type': 'array', 'items': {}}

count = 2
t = {'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': 'array', 'items': {}}}

count = 3
{'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': 'array', 'items': {}}}}
```

how to get t value dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
def build(count, s = {}):
  return {'type': 'array', 'items': s if count == 1 else build(count-1)}
```

---

```
for i in range(1, 4):
  print(build(i))
```

Output:

```
{'type': 'array', 'items': {}}
{'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': 'array', 'items': {}}}
{'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': 'array', 'items': {}}}}
```

Comment: Is there a difference to just use `'items': {}` instead of `s`?

Comment: using mutable objects as default arguments is a bad idea

Comment: @HenryYik It seems that the OP is relying on a base value `t = {}`. Utilizing a default argument to store the base value is one such way to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

using simple iteration:

```
count = 3
t = {}
for _ in range(count):
    t = {'type': 'array', 'items': t}

print(t)
#Output:
{'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': 'array', 'items': {}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you need some kind of looping action, but here at least is a hard wired way to proceed.

```
t = {'type': 'array', 'items': {}}

count = 1

t.update({'items': t}) 

count = 2

t['items'].update({'items': t}) 

count = 3

t['items']['items'].update({'items': t})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def dynamically_add(count):
        dict ={}
        for i in range(1,count+1):
            dict = {'type': 'array', 'items': dict}
        return dict
        #print(dynamically_add(2))
```